# Not possible to enter date manually in react-day-picker

Tags: react-day-picker

When entering a date manually, i.e. without using the day picker, no event is triggered. It should be possible to enter dates manually without using the picker.

Answer (score 0):

It works normally:

https://codesandbox.io/s/q3yqxkq209

but you have to check if date is valid, if is not in `onDayChange` callback is passed `undefined` as value, if you manually set `2018-09-01` it works as expected.